# How to get Quickblox avatar images

Tags: quickblox

I am using
QBChatMessage
to get all messages sent in the chat.

How can I get the sender's profile photo and user ID?

Answer (score 1):

User ID:

```
message.senderID
```

Avatar:

1) Get user body by ID:

```
 [QBUsers userWithID:message.senderID delegate:self];
```

2) Download avatar http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Update_profile_picture_.28avatar.29